# Opening jQuery dialog when clicking on a partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have a page that has some content and 3 partial views each holding an HTML table. I want to open a jQuery dialog when I click on a cell in one of the partial views that will superimpose itself over the entire page (partials included).

I'm not really sure how to check in my main page if something has been clicked in my partial view.

I tried creating the dialog in the partial but it doesn't open when I click on something.

Is there a way of implementing this?

This is the code I use in my main page for displaying the partial

```
<div id="PartialProvider">
    @Html.Action("DisplayProviderTable", "CaseInfo")
</div>
```

This is the content I want to put in a dialog which is in my main view.

```
<div id="Providers">
   ...
</div>
```

This is the code in my partial

```
<table>
     ....
   <tr>
       <td class="row" style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration:underline;" onclick="DisplayDialog(@Model.ID)">
        @Model.ID
    </td>
   </tr>
     ....
</table>
```

So basically when I click on that cell in my table in the partial I want to put the div providers in a dialog in my main view.

Comment: the javscript you put in your main page can see the dom of the partial View Included .

Comment: You can try to put for example <div id="test"> in your partialView 
and in your main view alert(document.getElementById("test").innerHTML)
You will see the the html in the DIV

Comment: Do you have a link to your code, maybe a jsFiddle?

Comment: I do have a div in my partial that contains the information I want to display in my dialog. Where would I need to use the $('#Mydivname').dialog('open')? Thanks

Comment: @brasewel Mark it as answer if it solved your problem, chances are someone else have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to reflect the answer:

**brasewel:** If my table only has a single cell that needs to be clicked, will something like `$('#tablename').click(function () { ...});` work in my main view?

**Me:** That cell must be marked by an `Id`, `class` or something like that. 
based on that you can find it by a `css selector` and attach an event to it or it's parent element which can be a `td`, `tr` or `table`.

Here is a code sinppet that we used for showing errors to user, it's a helper method

```
@helper ShowErrorServerSide(List<string> inputError, string dialogMessage)
{
    var errors = inputError;

    if (errors != null && errors.Count() > 0)
    {
<div id="dialog" title="@dialogMessage" style="display: none;">
    @foreach (var error in errors)
    {
        <p>@error</p>
    }
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeText: 'hide',
            buttons: { "Ok": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
        });
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });        
</script>
    }
}
```

Comment: Jani I know how to open a dialog. I'm not sure how to check and open one if I have clicked something in a partial view.

Comment: your partial view which contains an table which must has an ID. by that ID you can attach a click event to that element or it's child.

Comment: If my table only has a single cell that needs to be clicked, will something like $('#tablename').click(function () { ...}); work in my main view?

Comment: That cell must be marked by an Id, class or something like that. based on that you can find it by a css selector and attach an event to it or it's parent element which can be a `td`, `tr` or `table`.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. I simply put an id on the td and used $('#tdname').click(.....) and it recognizes the click event.

Comment: Posting this question here since it's kind of related. If I refresh the div(by reloading the partial), clicking on the td element by using the td id doesn't register a click event anymore. Any reason why it may be doing this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5724/discussion-between-brasewel-and-jani)